# Selenium HtmlUnitDriver clicking on checkbox

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, checkbox, htmlunit

I'm trying to get my checkbox clicked while running using selenium.

I have no issue running my test when using chromedriver.
But when I switch to `HtmlUnitDriver`, it will throw error when it reaches the clicking of checkbox action. The error thrown is

> org.openga.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: You may only interact with visible elements

I've tried multiple methods like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"chkConfirm\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"chkConfirm\"]")).click();
```

But none of it works. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I've tried both the suggested answer but none works.

So I decided to move on to PhantomJS and it works.

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='chkConfirm']"))
checkBox.isDisplayed();
if(!checkBox.isSelected())
checkBox.click();
```

Try this block.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add wait before clicking on the element? See an example below.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"chkConfirm\"]")));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"chkConfirm\"]")).click();
```